# Google Bigquery Permissions Issue

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two GCP projects. Project A and Project B. Under project A, I have a Bigquery data set and an IAM user - IAM-BQ-PROJ-A with roles `BigQuery Data Viewer` and `BigQuery User`.

Project B hosts a Kubernetes cluster. There is a Rails application in project B that is executing queries against the Bigquery dataset in project A. I have the credentials for IAM user - IAM-BQ-PROJ-A accessible to the Rails app. However, these queries fail with the following error -

```
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: accessDenied: Access Denied: Project B: The user IAM-BQ-PROJ-A does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in Project B.
```

These queries run successfully when the Rails application is running in the local development environment outside of GCP.

If I create an IAM user - IAM-BQ-PROJ-A under Project B with roles `BigQuery Data Viewer` and `BigQuery User` then these queries execute successfully.

Why is this the case? Shouldn't these queries fire successfully without having an IAM user under project B provided that the credentials are accessible (similar to the local dev environment functionality)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior since you are using 2 different projects.

The user created under project A might have the right permissions, but it has nothing to do with project B, so it won't have the permissions needed to perform the queries from project B. That's why you get the error:

```
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: accessDenied: Access Denied: Project B: The user IAM-BQ-PROJ-A does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in Project B.
```

Therefore creating the user under project B with the right permissions would allow the queries to be executed successfully.